# How to make regular expression "prefer" something?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
function getSrc($content) {
    $pattern = '<(?:content|src)="((?:https?://\d+\.media\.tumblr\.com)/(?:\w+)/(?:tumblr_[^_]+_(?:1280|500|400|250)\.(?:png|jpg|gif)))">i';
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}
```

in case content in this order:

```
...500.jpg...
...1280.jpg...
...400.jpg...
```

the $matches[1] would be 500, since 500 show up before 1280, but I would like 1280 when there has one.

Is it possible making the regular expression prefer to return bigger number?

finally, I change my code for life saving:

```
function getSrc($content) {
    $pattern = '<(?:content|src)="((?:https?://\d+\.media\.tumblr\.com)/(?:\w+)/(?:tumblr_[^_]+_(1280|500|400|250)\.(?:png|jpg|gif)))">i';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
    array_multisort($matches[2], SORT_DESC, $matches[1]);

    return $matches[1][0];
}
```

Comment: Since all of your alternation's are constant expressions, you don't need a regex for this. Use string functions to find what/which priority you are looking for. If its done with regex its slower and you will find that you are not able to add other factored subexpressions common to each alternation, rendering the regex ultimately useless.

Comment: @sln thanks for your comment, I'm coding for url fetching and this is simpler code just for example.

Comment: As I said before, I do not see any allowance for variability in your regular expression and is generally not possible. This is because a regex _Alternation_ is the only _Prefer_ available in regular expressions. Since your expression requires anchors `tumblr_[^_]+_(1280|500|400|250)\.(?:png|jpg|gif)))">` to locate the file name, there can be no variability engineered into the alternations. It starts/ends with constants.

Comment: You are better off running priority driven separate expressions on the same file.

Comment: @sln good idea, separate expressions! I make a loop and it perform better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with a serious caveat: it's much slower because it rescans the string for each option:

```
$pattern = '<^(.*(1280)|.*(500)|.*(400)|.*(250))">';
```

Basically, `^` anchors the regex to the left, then each option is matched in full. Obviously, this is very inefficient for long strings, but it does the trick.

Also, I apologize if it's not the function of them, but I'm assuming the regex is meant to match something like `1280"`, but if the `"` was not intended, it seems this would be preferable:

```
$pattern = '<^(.*(1280)|.*(500)|.*(400)|.*(250))>';
```

When extracting, use groups 2 through 5. Alternatively, remove the excess group parenthesis, and do a second match to `'<(1280|500|400|250)>'` to extract the value.

Note: the options in this answer don't use the case-insensitive tag, but you can always include if it's needed due to some other part of your regex.

Comment: Your `$` will cause the regex to match nothing, since it is end of string anchor. `^` is the beginning of string anchor, which fits the use case here.

Comment: @nhahtdh Oh gosh, that's embarrassing. Thanks for correcting it. I think it may be getting to late at night here for me to be posting answering questions now, or perhaps I've just lost my whits.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I would like to paste my full code for better reading: